# ArgumentError invalid date in DateTime#change

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When doing

```
startTime = DateTime.now
startTime = startTime.change(:min => (startTime.min / 5.to_f).ceil * 5)
```

our production server occasionally produces the following exception

```
A ArgumentError occurred in controller#action:

invalid date
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2009.10/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1519:in `civil'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:37:in `change'
```

And I just can't figure out what causes the problem nor reproduce it in my development environment. Am I doing something wrong, or what is happening here? What I want to do is create a DateTime instance which is rounded up to the closest 5 min from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DateTime.now.min > 55, then you are setting the min value to 60.

If you only need the time part:

```
startTime = DateTime.now
new_minute = startTime.min / 5.to_f).ceil * 5
new_hour = DateTime.now.hour

if new_minute == 60
  new_minute = 0
  new_hour = new_hour + 1
end

new_time = startTime.change(:min => new_minute, :hour => new_hour)
```

if you need more than this, I'd suggest using `activesupport`. Then you could do

```
new_time = startTime + (new_minute - min).minutes
```

Comment: Thanks for making me see that. My final version became

startTime = DateTime.now.change(:sec => 0);
roundedMinutes = (startTime.min / 5.0).ceil * 5;
startTime = (startTime + (roundedMinutes - startTime.min).minutes);

which adds the "missing" minutes to the date (also fixes day changes at 23:56-23:59) and sets the seconds to 0.